# How do I pass variables to anonymous functions?

Tags: php, laravel, email

Why on earth is Laravel saying email is not a defined variable???

```
$title = 'hi';
$content = 'hi';
$email='topher@site.com';

Mail::send('confirmation', ['title' => $title, 'content' => $content], function ($message) {
 $message->from('john@site.com', 'Topher');
 $message->to($email);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using it in a function, and thats a different scope. Add `use($email)` after your functions arguments.

`function($message) use($email)`

Answer (score 3):

Because you are accessing the `$email` variable inside another function scope.

Instead of

```
Mail::send('confirmation', ['title' => $title, 'content' => $content], function ($message) {
```

Add `use` keyword to include the `$email` variable inside the closure function's scope.

```
Mail::send('confirmation', ['title' => $title, 'content' => $content], function ($message) use($email) {
```

Answer (score 0):

It's outside the scope of your function. Try this:

```
$title = 'hi';
$content = 'hi';

Mail::send('confirmation', ['title' => $title, 'content' => $content], function ($message) {
    $email='topher@site.com';
    $message->from('john@site.com', 'Topher');
    $message->to($email);
});
```

Comment: I'm assuming the email is not actually going to be hard-coded in the script like that and doing it this way was just an example of simplifying the code for the sake of asking the question. If it is hard-coded, that's bad practice. It would be better to store it in a config variable somewhere, or at the very least in a class property defined at the beginning of the class.